# Python 3.10.2 won't run on MacBook Air macOS Monterey (12.1)

Tags: python

Having trouble getting python to work on my Mac, PyCharm refuses to open so I've attempted the VS code add on to no avail. I have python compatible with my Mac installed, attempting to make it my default language but it seems there is something I'm missing as my friend who has a similar Mac doesn't have the same issue even if the processes look identical to mine.

Comment: No idea why you're having a problem. I run 3.10.2 (venv) standalone and from VS Code on macOS 12.1 without any issues

Comment: That makes you and me both. It's a MacBook Air 2017 running intel core i5, a friend of mine managed to get it working on an older Air with no issue. Using Jupiter notebook as my best work around at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Monterey on local environment then the versions you need are:
**Python 2 is version 2.1.18 and Python 3 is version 3.8.9**

but if it's necessary to run python 10.2 you can do it with a virtual environment.

Comment: Appreciate the response, if it was that simple I wouldn't be scratching my head about it to this day. My assumption is that there is a deeper issue I'm yet to discover but so far I have found an alternative in the meantime. Jupiter Notebook seems to be working fine, unlike PyCharm or VS code which I'm assuming are the IDEs you're referring to?